# Three.js change rotation on click

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I want to change/start an animated rotation of an object when I click a button. I understand that the render funciton is an infinite loop and that cylinder.rotation.x += 0.1 adds up the angle and makes the thing go round. I want to change start this parameter using a button. So far I only managed to add to the rotation once, while the button is clicked. Maybe the working example will explain better:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>3D Cube</title>
        <style>

            canvas { width: 100%; 
            height: 100% }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="three.js"></script>
        <script>

            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var cylindergeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.1, 0.1, 2, 50, false);
            var cylindermaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({wireframe: true, color: 0x000000});
            var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(cylindergeometry, cylindermaterial);
            cylinder.position.set(0,0,0);
            scene.add(cylinder);

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);

                cylinder.rotation.x = 0.1;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");     
            btn.appendChild(t);    
            document.body.appendChild(btn);


            btn.onclick=function(){
                // start animation
                // change cylinder.rotation.x = 0.1; to cylinder.rotation.x += 0.1;
            };
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move `render()` inside `onclick`.

```
var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  cylinder.rotation.x += 0.1;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

btn.onclick = function() {
  render();
};
```

This works for your specific problem, but probably isn't a good solution if you wanted to do more complicated logic. Instead, you could separate the rendering and cylinder logic into something like this:

```
/* global render function */
var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
render();

/* cylinder rotation logic */
var rotateCylinder = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(rotateCylinder);
  cylinder.rotation.x += 0.1;
};

/* start the rotation */
btn.onclick = function() {
  rotateCylinder();
};
```

This is totally off the top of my head and might have its own drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Make that "0.1" a value inside a variable and change that variable inside the onclick callback. Actually, make that variable start as zero. Then you increment to 0.1 inside the button's callback.

```
...
camera.position.z = 5;

var rotationAmount = 0.0; // initial value is zero so it starts not rotating.

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    // make 0.1 a variable and increment the rotation, by that variable, between every frame.
    cylinder.rotation.x += rotationAmount; // starts without any rotation. even though "+=" is there.
    // without "+=" your object won't rotate as frames change. it would stand still in a 0.1 angle, frame after frame.

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
...
```

Your onclick callback. animation will start after first click on button.

```
...
btn.onclick=function(){
    // start animation
    // change cylinder.rotation.x = 0.1; to cylinder.rotation.x += 0.1;

    // changing variable inside onclick callback.
    rotationAmount += 0.1 // every click on that button will make rotation faster. it started at zero, first click will put it to 0.1.
    // or add any other logic you can imagine using this button.
    if (rotationAtmount > 0.1) 
        rotationAtmount = 0 // 1 click starts, 1 click stops.
};
...
```